# Is it possible to bundle/minimize ONLY the node_modules folder with webpack?

Tags: webpack, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I have a relatively small codebase which requires not to be bundled and I need to keep the folder structure in the output. Yet, `node_modules` folder is quite large and I'd like to keep it bundled?/minimized with dead code elimination.

Example folder structure:

`- bin/file-1.js
- bin/file-2.js
- bin/folder-A/file-A1.js
- bin/folder-A/file-A2.js
- bin/folder-B/file-B1.js
- bin/folder-B/file-B2.js
- bin/folder-B/folder-BB/file-BB1.js
- bin/folder-B/folder-BB/file-BB2.js
- node_modules/module-1
- node_modules/module-2
- node_modules/module-3
- node_modules/module-4`

I just need all 4 modules under `node_modules` minimized so that it won't take so much space when I deploy it with serverless fw to AWS lambda

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [node-prune](https://github.com/tj/node-prune). So much easier and actually reduced size is smaller than when webpack is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yarn to make use of its autoclean feature, I wrote a .yarnclean file which is a combination of the default file created by yarn in combination of the extensions deleted by node-prune.

Then using serverless-webpack's "scripts" config option you can run yarnclean to cleanup your node_modules. as described here https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/519#issuecomment-577727171

you can see my full setup here which includes a few more improvements you can do to get the optimal package size https://medium.com/faun/how-to-optimise-your-serverless-typescript-webpack-eslint-setup-for-performance-86d052284505